# How do I make a button determine its table position, call a function and send arguments to it?

Tags: javascript, php, button, onclick, html-table

I have created a table in HTML/PHP with the columns ID-Name-Button. Now, when the button to a specific row is clicked, I would like to call a function that builds me a string and then opens the link contained in the string.

The 2 problems I have is:

1. How do I manage get the current table position of the button and fetch the data in the first 2 cells?
2. How do I give that data to my javascript function and then return it? (I have the function of how to build the URL and all, I just need the table data to complete it)

Sorry if these seem like dumb questions, I'm very new to PHP/Javascript.

EDIT:
Here is how I generate the table (It's Facebook-related, by the way, creates a list of the friends):

```
echo "<form id='xy' method='post' action='index.php'>";
echo "<table><tbody><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Button</th>";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($friends[data]); ++$i)
    {

        echo "<tr><td>".$friends[data][$i]["id"]."</td><td>".$friends[data][$i]["name"]."</td><td><input type='submit' onClick='BuildFeedURL()' value='Nachricht senden (FeedDialog)'/></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Comment: Can you include your relevent code here

Comment: Show us how you are generating the table.. it's important to know that in order to be able to give you an idea on how to move on! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boehmi, no one is dumb. Both problems can be easily solved using JQUERY

before that you have to update your html little bit:

```
echo "<tr><td class='fids'>".$friends[data][$i]["id"]."</td><td class="fname">".$friends[data][$i]["name"]."</td><td><input type='submit' onClick='BuildFeedURL(this)' value='Nachricht senden (FeedDialog)'/></td></tr>";
```

note the classes added to td's, and `this` to buildfeedurl(this);
I dont know why you have used `input type='submit'`, as you can redirect/reload page using javascript.

Using jquery's [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/%E2%80%8E) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
buildfeedurl(obj) {
 var fid = $(obj).parent().parent().find('.fid').html();    // .html() can be replaced with .text() too
 var fname = $(obj).parent().parent().find('.fname').html();    // .html() can be replaced with .text() too
    {
      // do your processing of url building
    }

    // here you can redirect to your required URL
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

No need of passing values to another function....

Answer (score 0):

its easy with jquery

```
 $('button').click(function(){
 var td= $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
 var id=$(td[0]).html();
 var name=$(td[1]).html();
 var yourstring = 'id="'+id+'" name="'+name+'"';
 alert(yourstring);
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XQMEv/1)